# Failed to compile Core Data model in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, xcode7

I have made some good progress on an iOS app this summer, then suddenly, a few weeks ago, it wouldn't compile.

I can't post pictures, but the error says:

> /Users/Magnus/OneDrive/Xcode/Achieve/Achieve/DataModel.xcdatamodeld:
>   Failed to compile model at
>   /Users/Magnus/OneDrive/Xcode/Achieve/Achieve/DataModel.xcdatamodeld

I have tried to delete the reference, and add it again, removed duplicate files, cleaned the project, and made a new Model file, but nothing helps. Any ideas? I really want to continue to work on the app.

Comment: If you create a new project from one of the Xcode templates that includes Core Data, will that project compile its data model?

Comment: Did you try manually deleting the model? If not try using "Show in Finder" at one of the model versions and delete model version. Manual deletion should solve it.

Comment: OK, that's strange. I can't even compile a new project with Core Data. Same problem... And I have tried deleting one of the model versions.

Comment: Reinstall Xcode I guess. If a new project can't compile models, something's broken that's not part of your project.

Comment: Okay, that worked! I should have tested a new project with Core Data a long time ago, but at least it is fixed now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solved! If anyone else has the same problem, reinstalling Xcode fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this issue , what i have done is

1. Create a brand new project with same name and same package name
2. In the terminal of the project directory Pod init
3. Open the pod file in a editor
4. Copy and paste the old project pod files into the new one
5. Copy **all** files and resources to the new project
6. Simply do Pod install

And it worked like charm! 
Try this one if nothing work .